# EF Core Join Table for One To Many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Database Schema like this.

[image: Database schema]

I am working on gettingDetailByPostID API which needs to return 1 Object as follows.

```
    Guid PostId;
    Guid UserId;
    String? Username;
    String? MediaPath;
    int Likes; // count the number of likes of the post
    String? Caption;
    bool IsLiked;
    IEnumerable<Comment>? Comments; // List of comments in the post
```

I am having difficulty in joining the tables together to get more data from the User and Comment tables. How can I do this with ef core 6.

Comment: Instead of posting images, post your model classes.

Comment: Can you show classes UserProfile, Post, Likes and Comment ?

Answer (score 0):

firsr have a `DbSet` property for in your db context inherited class which may look like this   `public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }`.

then inject the dbcontext to your required service as constructor injection.

the you can do `var post = yourDbContenxt.Posts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=>p.PostId==yourPostId);`

Comment: i know but i am having difficulty in joining the tables together to get more data from the User and Comment tables. Thank you.

Comment: var post = yourDbContenxt.Posts.Include(i=>i.Comments).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=>p.PostId==yourPostId); and similarly to user

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be in a single transaction.
I believe you already have configured EF with navigation and you should have an entities like this

```
    public class Post
    {
        public int post_id { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string caption { get; set; }
        public string? media_path { get; set; }
        virtual public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    }
    public class Like
    {
        public int post_id { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        virtual public Post Post { get; set; }
        virtual public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserProfile
    {
        public int post_id { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        virtual public Post Post { get; set; }
        virtual public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    }
```

If not, you should have a look on the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) or on this great [tutorial site](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

If it is configured with navigation (but without lazy loading to avoid infinite loop, and to have an ecological use of your server ressources :) )

Then you can build your object within the same context instanciation such as this short exemple

```
 public class DetailedPost
    {
        Guid PostId;
        Guid UserId;
        String? Username;
        String? MediaPath;
        int Likes; // count the number of likes of the post
        String? Caption;
        bool IsLiked;
        IEnumerable<Comment>? Comments; // List of comments in the post
        
        public DetailedPost GettingDetailByPostID(int id)
        {
            DbContext context = new DbContext();

            UserProfile userprofile = context.UserProfile
                .Include(user => user.Posts.Where(p => p.post_id == id)) // Select post by id
                .ThenInclude(post => post.Comments) // Include the Comment Db relative to post selected
                .Include(user => user.Likes); // Include like db relative to userProfile db

// Return object construction
            return new DetailedPost()
            {
                PostId = userprofile.post_id,
                UserId = userprofile.user_id,
                Username = userprofile.username,
                Caption = userprofile.Posts.FirstOrDefault().Caption,
                Likes = userprofiles.Likes.Count(),

            };

        }
    }
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: great, it solved my problem when i kept thinking that having to join the tables together can solve this problem.
Thanks very much.